# How to pass each element in a list as arguments of another function in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I got a list (in my situation the number of elements in the list is variable),

```
    tmp=c('X1','X2','X3','X4')
```

I'd like to pass each element to the expand grid function like this:

```
    tmp1=expand.grid(X1=c(0,1),X2=c(0,1),X3=c(0,1),X4=c(0,1))
```

where each element can just take values 0 and 1. How could I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: @mackbox Note that you get some points for accepting answers if that is any motivation for accepting any of the answers to previous questions that have worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mget` to get the values of the elements in the 'tmp' `vector` as a `list` and then wrap it with `expand.grid`.

```
expand.grid(mget(tmp))
```

Or if these are not objects, but the column names we need to create with `expand.grid`, then place the vector `c(0,1)` in a `list`, replicate it by the `length` of 'tmp', do the `expand.grid` and set the column names as 'tmp' (with `setNames`)

```
setNames(expand.grid(rep(list(0:1), length(tmp))), tmp)
#    X1 X2 X3 X4
#1   0  0  0  0
#2   1  0  0  0
#3   0  1  0  0
#4   1  1  0  0
#5   0  0  1  0
#6   1  0  1  0
#7   0  1  1  0
#8   1  1  1  0
#9   0  0  0  1
#10  1  0  0  1
#11  0  1  0  1
#12  1  1  0  1
#13  0  0  1  1
#14  1  0  1  1
#15  0  1  1  1
#16  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: @mackbox I am not sure I followed your comment.  If the "X1" is already defined as an object, you can use the first option.